# display { and } as function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am having problems displaying { and } as text in React. I saw a similar question that someone said to wrap the entire string in curlies, but this is not working for me

this is my code

```
    render(){
        let component = {
            activemenu:0,
            nameapps:"App Sekolah Dev",
            iconapps:"fas fa-cubes",
            miniicon:"fas fa-box-open",
            logoapps:"../assets/img/avatar/avatar-1.png",
            classname:"form-control",
            menuapps:["Tab (tabPage.js)", "Button (buttonPage.js)", "Input (inputPage.js)", "Blocker (blockerPage.js)", "Table (tablePage.js)", "Alert (alertPage.js)", "Dialog (dialogPage.js)", "Combobox (comboboxPage.js)", "Step (stepPage.js)", "Function Button"],
            linkapps:["./tabPage", "./buttonPage", "./inputPage", "./blockerPage", "./tablePage", "./alertPage", "./dialogPage", "./comboboxPage", "./stepPage", "./functionbuttonPage"],
            iconmenu:["fas fa-rocket", "fas fa-cubes", "fas fa-rocket", "fas fa-cubes", "fas fa-rocket", "fas fa-cubes", "fas fa-rocket", "fas fa-cubes", "fas fa-rocket", "fas fa-cubes"],
            halamanapps:["homePage", "tabPage", "buttonPage", "inputPage", "blockerPage", "tablePage", "alertPage", "dialogPage", "comboboxPage", "stepPage", "functionbuttonPage"],
        }
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <body className="page-after-loader">
                    <div className="main-wrapper">
                        <div className="navbar-bg"></div>
                        <Header />
                        <Sidebar {...component}/>
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                </body>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
```

i want return { and } in this code

```
let halaman=[];
        for(let [index, halamanapps] of this.props.halamanapps.entries()){
            if (halamanapps == 'homePage') {
                halaman.push(
                    <Route exact path="/" component={'{' + halamanapps + '}'}/>
                );
            }else{
                halaman.push(
                    <Route path={"/" + halamanapps} component={'{' + halamanapps + '}'}/>
                );
            }
        }


return (
<React.Fragment>
    <div className="content">
    {halaman}
    </div>
</React.Fragment>
);
```

example result of halaman is `tabPane` i want to return halaman is `{tabpane}`

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand the situation here. are you referring to this part?  `<Route exact path="/" component={'{' + halamanapps + '}'}/>`

Comment: sorry if the explanation I gave was not clear. yes my problem is in the code

Comment: I see you, you need to loop the `halaman` in the render function.
calling it directly using `{halaman}` will not work

Comment: sorry I just learned react last week so I don't really understand the syntax. The syntax above runs smoothly, but the problem is here with the ```component``` tag.  now the return of component is ```component= halamanapps``` i want to add ```{ and }``` in component tag so that the results become ```component={halamanapps }```

Comment: Hi Gilang, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your query correctly, then you just need to iterate over the array and generate the `Route`,

```
halamanapps:["homePage", "tabPage", "buttonPage", "inputPage", "blockerPage", "tablePage", "alertPage", "dialogPage", "comboboxPage", "stepPage", "functionbuttonPage"]
```

In `React`, component names should be in `PascalCase`, so I advise you to change your array to this,

```
halamanapps:["HomePage", "TabPage", "ButtonPage", "InputPage", "BlockerPage", "TablePage", "AlertPage", "DialogPage", "ComboboxPage", "StepPage", "FunctionbuttonPage"]
```

Now the iteration is simple,

```
for(let [index, halamanapps] of this.props.halamanapps.entries()){
  if (halamanapps === 'HomePage') {
      halaman.push(
          <Route exact path="/" component={halamanapps}/>
      );
  }else{
      halaman.push(
          <Route path={`/${halamanapps}`} component={halamanapps}/>  //path uses template string
      );
  }
}
```

Read more about [Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

---

The simple way is iterate using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will give you another array, so you don't need to push your `Route` in array again.

```
let halaman = this.props.halamanapps.map( halamanapps => (
    return halamanapps === 'HomePage' ? <Route exact path="/" component={halamanapps}/> : <Route path={`/${halamanapps}`} component={halamanapps}/>
))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice and comments. I have managed to find a solution because of your comments